# Need to resize "like" button

Tags: html, button, facebook-like

We want to resize the "like" button as we have complaints from  Users it's too small on smartphones. We are using HTML5 code. We cannot use iframe as we need to determine user has clicked on "like" button for out social wifi application.

As I mentioned we have constant complaints that the "like" button is too small on smartphones . . . these are users not us saying this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS3 `transform` to `scale` the Facebook button:

#### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/E8UA8/)

```
#fblike {
    transform: scale(2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    -moz-transform: scale(2);
    -ms-transform: scale(2);
}
```

[image: FB Like x2]

---

***Note:*** you can use a float for `scale`, e.g: `1.5` = 150% of the original size.